# keypress doesn't work in function i made for some chat application

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I have some problem with key press when calling the  key press in my function it does not work at all even I use multiple solution for it 
so I try to call a difference method key up or key down but it also not work

```
chat.connection.start().done(function () {
  var connectionname = prompt();
  chat.server.setConnectionName(connectionname);
  $("#myConnectionName").val(connectionname);
  $("inmessage").keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
      var partnerId = $(this).closest('#chatBox').find('#partnerConnectionId').val();
      var message = $(this).val();
      chat.server.send(partnerId, message);
      $(this).val('');
    }
  });
)
```

It show no error method but it does not work also for other keydown.

Comment: Have you tried to use `.on( "keypress", () => {...} )`. It is suggested from documentation too:
https://api.jquery.com/keypress/

Comment: Can you show us you HTML?  ```$("inmessage")``` - isn't a valid selector.

Comment: `$('inmessage')` is literally looking for the element(s) `<inmessage>`. Is it the desired behavior or, perhaps, you wanted `$('#inmessage')` or `$('.inmessage')` instead?

Comment: <input type="text" id="inmessage" class="inmessage">

Answer (score 0):

As @briosheje mentioned in comments you need to use a class or id selector :

```
chat.connection.start().done(function () {
  var connectionname = prompt();
  chat.server.setConnectionName(connectionname);
  $("#myConnectionName").val(connectionname);
  $(".inmessage").keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
      var partnerId = $(this).closest('#chatBox').find('#partnerConnectionId').val();
      var message = $(this).val();
      chat.server.send(partnerId, message);
      $(this).val('');
    }
  });
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  var connectionname = prompt();
  chat.server.setConnectionName(connectionname);
  $("#myConnectionName").val(connectionname);

  $(".inmessage" **or** "#inmessage").keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
      var partnerId = $(this).closest('#chatBox').find('#partnerConnectionId').val();
      var message = $(this).val();
      chat.server.send(partnerId, message);
      $(this).val('');
    }
  });
)
```